# Is it possible to draw an Apache eCharts grid heatmap on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, heatmap, apache-echarts

I'm trying to draw an Apache eCharts grid heatmap on Google Maps to achieve the result shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHUn5.jpg) from the following address: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=map-bin.

I have attempted to use the [echarts-extension-gmap](https://github.com/plainheart/echarts-extension-gmap) project, but it doesn't seem to support the desired kind of chart.

Is there another open source library or a way to adapt Apache eCharts to draw this heat map on a Google Map?

Thank you.